# Rails in Docker long waits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a Rails app configured in Docker for development.  When I run `docker-compose up`, the container starts and all the associated ones specified in my `docker-compose.yml` file do as well.  It all works fine, apart from the fact that my app container takes ages to start.  Once started it is perfect.  I'm rather unsure where to start to find out what is causing this delay.  It could be a Rails OR Docker issue.  I do not have this issue in other Docker/Rails applications, Just this one.

I know this isn't much to go on, but i'm hoping people could give me some pointers as to where to look to try to find where this delay is coming from or what's happening in that time and then I can post more information to help narrow it down.

Thanks

Dockerfile:

```
FROM starefossen/ruby-node:2-8-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
CMD ["rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 35729:35729
      - 5000:5000
      - 9200:9200
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - type: tmpfs
        target: /app/tmp/pids/
    depends_on:
      - database
      - elasticsearch

  database:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  webpacker:
    build: .
    command: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - '3035:3035'

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.4.1
    volumes:
      - es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

volumes:
  pg-data:
  es-data:
```

Comment: Please specify what kind of base image you're using, and more specific things about your environment. Without that information, it's impossible to know what and where can something have gone wrong.

Comment: @jjmerelo I've attached my dockerfile and docker-compose files to my OP. It's a Rails 5 app that i've recently switched over to Webpacker.  It could be webpacker that's causing ti but i'm unsure how to see the output and what's causing the delay.

Comment: @rctnell my money is on bundle install. Anything related to the network could cause long waits if it's not configured correctly.

Comment: @jjmerelo But surely the `bundle install` is done when the container image is built the first time? Yes that tales it's usual time but the delay i'm experiencing is happening when i just use `docker-compose up` AFTER the image has been built.

Comment: @jjmerelo The delay happens for any command I want to run. For example `docker-compose run app rails c` .  This works but has the long delay before i see the rails terminal.

Comment: you are right, that should happen only the first time. You are also restarting adminer `always`. But there's so much stuff there, you'd be better off picking it apart, container by container, to see which one's the culprit. It might be the webpack dev server as you say, but it might also be any of the others... Using some kind of logging might help too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185981/discussion-between-rctneil-and-jjmerelo).